# Angstrom eMMC root remount

Tags: root, mount

I have an I.MX6 embedded system with an Angstrom Linux.
By adding the kernel parameter init=/bin/sh to the boot arguments I have now root access to the system. Now I want to add/change a user.

But the root is mounted as read only.

```
    cat /etc/fstab
    rootfs               /                    squashfs   defaults              0  0
    proc                 /proc                proc       defaults              0  0
    devpts               /dev/pts             devpts     mode=0620,gid=5       0  0
    tmpfs                /tmp                 tmpfs      defaults              0  0
    /dev/mmcblk0p1       /appconfig           ext2       defaults              0  0
    /dev/mmcblk0p2       /media/kernel_1      ext2       noauto                0  0
    /dev/mmcblk0p3       /media/kernel_2      ext2       noauto                0  0
    /dev/mmcblk0p5       /media/rootfs_b      f2fs       noauto                0  0
    /dev/mmcblk0p6       /media/rootfs_1      squashfs   noauto,nofail,ro      0  0
    /dev/mmcblk0p7       /media/rootfs_2      squashfs   noauto,nofail,ro      0  0
    /dev/mmcblk0p8       /var                 f2fs       defaults              0  0
```

There are two kernels, actual kernel_1 with rootfs_1 is running.

I tried to use `mount -o remount,rw /` but this isn't working.
The command mount isn't working ether:

```
mount: failed to read mtab: No such file or directory


    [    1.500600] mmc0: SDHCI controller on 2198000.usdhc [2198000.usdhc] using ADMA
    [    1.541992] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
    [    1.560080] NET: Registered protocol family 10
    [    1.569834] sit: IPv6 over IPv4 tunneling driver
    [    1.581656] NET: Registered protocol family 17
    [    1.587361] Key type dns_resolver registered
    [    1.596955] ThumbEE CPU extension supported.
    [    1.601296] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
    [    1.607158] mmc0: MAN_BKOPS_EN bit is not set
    [    1.614429] registered taskstats version 1
    [    1.630641] mmc0: new DDR MMC card at address 0001
    [    1.638019] Key type encrypted registered
    [    1.645244] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 P1XXXX 3.60 GiB
    [    1.652696] input: gpio_buttons@0 as /devices/soc0/gpio_buttons@0/input/input0
    [    1.662385] mmcblk0boot0: mmc0:0001 P1XXXX partition 1 2.00 MiB
    [    1.668707] snvs_rtc 20cc034.snvs-rtc-lp: setting system clock to 1970-01-01 00:04:09 UTC (249)
    [    1.677753] mmcblk0boot1: mmc0:0001 P1XXXX partition 2 2.00 MiB
    [    1.700312]  mmcblk0: p1 p2 p3 p4 < p5 p6 p7 p8 >
    [    1.806836] VFS: Mounted root (squashfs filesystem) readonly on device 179:7.
    [    1.818583] devtmpfs: mounted
    [    1.821894] Freeing unused kernel memory: 348K (c069f000 - c06f6000)
```

So I want to remount /dev/mmcblk0p6 (current root) as read-write.

Any idea?

Comment: I got some new points: I mounted /dev/mmcblk0p6 at /tmp/sq. Then I have done a copy of the data to another folder /var/tmp/rw. There I am able to mod some parts. But what now? Make a new squashfs with mksquashfs and write the file to /dev/mmcblk0p6? Will this work?